# Searching for a quotation manager

Tags: citations, online-resource, software, reference-managers, quotation

**I’m looking for a way to manage the text of the quotations  that most certainly I will use (i.e. quote) in the future**. I’m a philosopher, so this is specially handy —and even required— for the classical texts.

I'm currently using [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) to manage my references, which is fine for citations on daily working, but does not allow to add quotations to the library items.

I have checked [Wikindx](http://wikindx.sourceforge.net/) (a PHP-based manager which allow this), but it doesn't seem very consolidated… Currently, I keep my quotations in a mediawiki installation, but it is complicated and unoptimized (but at least gives me readability and long term security of accesibility).

Does anyone of you have the same trouble? Which manager can you recommend? Anyone knows if Mendeley has plans to add something like it?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75547/reference-manager-with-note-taking-quote-storing-capabilities

Answer (score 6):

[TextCite: Publication Quotation Manager](http://textcite.sourceforge.net/) looks like a thing you are looking for (haven't tried, only googled it):

> TextCite is a program for organizing and commenting textual citations from texts (books, articles, or other published works) for use in producing scientific or academic publications. You can organize by publication, author, category, or outline. It works with bibliographic management programs like Citation, EndNote, RefWorks, and BibTeX, providing important text/citation management capabilities that these programs lack, while still allowing for rapid footnote and bibliography generation by means of your favorite bibliography manager. It also exports to PDF and Word (RTF).

Answer (score 4):

Try [Citavi](http://www.citavi.com/en/features.html). It is a bibliographic (reference) manager and a knowledge manager. Citavi organizes references and respective PDFs (or other files) like Mendeley. Additionally, it stores quotations that you can directly copy from your PDFs (which links them automatically to the right reference), pictures and your own ideas. Furthermore, it has a Word Add-In and a so-called "Publication Assistent" which can also paste your quotations and references into OpenOffice or your favored TeX-editor.
The Citavi Free version can only edit Citavi project files with up to 100 references, but you can have as many projects as you want.

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to Academia Stack Exchange! One-line answers are somewhat discouraged here, so it would be good if you could quote some of the specific features of the software you mention, and how it compares with others…

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to using [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) for that purpose, there are two ways to do that:

- using notes for books (i.e. in each book you can copy and paste fragments to notes attached to that book) - a warning, though: there seems to be a maximum character limit to this field; text that gets too long is silently trimmed
- using single entries (`File -> Add Entry Manually`) e.g. as "book sections" with the quote in the "abstract" field (yeah, I know, it's on the verge on hacking the system).

When it comes to less specific solutions, you can use e.g. [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) (or any other note-taking software), each note for each textual citation.

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/75549/38524) like [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) does the search in annotations. And, [unlike Citavi](https://secure.citavi.com/635/purl-academic5), it's completely free.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version [Citavi 5](http://www.citavi.com), the quotes taken from PDF documents stay linked to the exact position in the PDF. You can also add comments or summaries to paragraphs or chapters, all of which stay linked to the PDF, so you can jump from the quotation back to the PDF.

Additionally, you can also add you own ideas, and organize and sort everything into categories. Those categories are going to be the chapters of your book or paper.

(BTW, I work for Citavi)