# How to read and organize academic materials

Tags: research-process, reading, note-taking

It's a questions that haunts me for some day. I am a phd in computer science and recently when I need to read materials of different forms and take note, I somehow don't know how to decide. With the research area of mine increases, I have to remember vividly more classic materials, or systemically build a way to review them. Currently, the materials include

1. Papers : only-mathematical wise, normally of pages 20-40, some are typically lengthy to 60 pages.
2. Classic books : 1) code/system wise, which I prefer to read on pc so I could probably code at the same time; 2) more mathematical wise, which I prefer to read on ipad so I could do derivation and take note.

The trade-off is that, the pc has larger screen and is more natural for me to read the books, while less convenient for me to take notes, especially for hand-written note. And it's even hard to collect the annotations and highlight on pdf reader. So I would like some sharing / suggestions / ideas of how to read materials(papers, books), organize and take notes ?

Notice that this is not a question about reference manager as [Reference manager with note-taking/quote-storing capabilities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75547/reference-manager-with-note-taking-quote-storing-capabilities), it's rather to balance the usage between pc and ipad for different materials and find a systematic way to combine the note-after-reading.

Comment: This differs between people, of course. But taking notes is probably the most important element. And do so in a way that will be preserved. I find that paper is best for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "[a holistic method on how to deal with knowledge in your life](https://zettelkasten.de/introduction/)", perhaps the *Zettelkasten* method might be something for you.